# After upgrade angular from 11 to 12, span.ant-radio+* -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: angular

as the title, when I upgrade my angular app from 11 to 12, then when I run the server on my local and go to any route, I see the following errors. but it seems all functions of my app work well.

Compiled successfully.
** Angular Universal Live Development Server is listening on http://localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
Server render: GET /dashboard

/dashboard

2 rules skipped due to selector errors:
span.ant-radio+* -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
span.ant-radio+* -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

does anyone know how to deal with that? thank you!

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "setup": "tsc setup-environments.ts && node setup-environments.js",
    "dev": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:single": "ng test --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix true",
    "sourcemapexplorer": "ng build --configuration production --source-map && source-map-explorer dist/my-app/browser/*.js --html source-map-explorer/report.html",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr --port 4200",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/my-app/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --configuration production && ng run my-app:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run my-app:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.16",
    "@antv/g2": "^4.1.13",
    "@ng-web-apis/common": "^1.9.0",
    "@ng-web-apis/universal": "^1.9.5",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.1.3",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.4",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^12.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.8",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.16",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^12.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue in Angular 13. Have you found a solution? This should be related to some deprecations.